# how to schedule ajax calls every N seconds?

Tags: javascript, ajax, http

If I want a whole page to reload every N seconds, I would put something like this in the HTML:
`meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5"`

Is there a standard practice for doing the same kind of thing for AJAX calls? I want schedule an AJAX call to go off every 10 seconds say, in order to update parts of the page, without refreshing the whole page. It would be even better if I could schedule multiple AJAX calls at different times, as some parts of the page may need to be updated more often than others.

TIA

Comment: Since setTimeout and setInterval have already been mentioned, you should probably take a look at John Resig's notes on how timers work in JavaScript - http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/

Comment: Looking at the jQuery library - there appears to be a popular plug-in designed to do specifically what I was after: http://www.360innovate.co.uk/blog/2009/03/periodicalupdater-for-jquery/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could use [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout) or [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval) (the latter is probably best suited to what you want to do).

```
setInterval(makeRequest, (10 * 1000));
```

...where `makeRequest` is a function that reloads some content via AJAX.

Comment: If you do this, I'd make sure to verify that the previous request has finished before starting another. You don't want to pile up requests if there's network lag.

Comment: @jtbandes: Good point. However, this logic would probably go into the "makeRequest" function.

Comment: @jtbandes, what will happen if the previous request has NOT finished when another is started?

Comment: @PeterLee It's just undesirable — for example, if one lags they could finish around the same time and so your UI might update irregularly. Or if there's a network error and none of the requests can get through, there's no point in sending more requests every few seconds.

Answer (score 5):

```
function proxy()
{
  /* implement call to your Ajax method */
}

setInterval( proxy, 1000 ); // last arg is in milliseconds
```

Answer (score 1):

```
You can use serInterval method of javascript:
Just write down the lines at the bottom of your page:

<script>
window.setInterval(function(){
  ajaxCallFunction();  //calling every 5 seconds
}, 5000);

function ajaxCallFunction(){
    //this function uses ajax to interact with the server
}
<script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that there is a servlet with URL Pattern **/UpdateCount** is configured in web.xml to provide dynamic data/content and there is a div element **countStatDiv** in the jsp page.

The following code refreshes/updates the content of **countStatDiv** at  every 30 seconds using GET method and variable **seconds** value can be changed according to the need:

```
                <script>
                    var request;
                    var seconds=30;
                    function getRequestObject(){
                    setInterval(function() {sendRequest();},seconds*1000);
                    if (window.ActiveXObject){
                    return (new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"));
                    } else if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
                    return(new XMLHttpRequest());
                    } else {
                    return (null);
                    }
                    }
                    function sendRequest(){
                    request = getRequestObject();
                    request.onreadystatechange = handleResponse;
                    request.open("GET", "../UpdateCount", true);
                    request.send(null);
                    }
                    function handleResponse(){
                    if((request.readyState == 4)&amp;&amp;(request.status == 200)){
                    var serverResponse = request.responseText;
                    var statCtrl=document.getElementById("countStatDiv");
                    statCtrl.innerHTML=serverResponse;
                    }
                    }
                </script>
```