# Reload contents from the log file on the page using AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I am running a shell script in the background and redirecting the output to a log file in php. I want to display the contents from the log file on the page. I am able to do that using the code below.

```
<?php   
    $logfile = "hello";  
?>
function displayOutput()
{
    var html = <?php
        echo filesize($logfile)
            ? json_encode(file_get_contents($logfile))
            : '"Log file is getting generated"'; 
        ?>;
    document.form.text1.value = html;
}
```

However, the log file keeps updating till the script completes executing. How can i reload the updated contents from the file on the same page?

Answer (score 1):

The technique that I developed + discuss here may be useful:

https://web.archive.org/web/20150206001444/http://commavee.com/2007/04/13/ajax-logfile-tailer-viewer/
It's been around for a while + works well.

Comment: Sorry, it's a broken link now

Answer (score 0):

You need to set an interval timer to call your function every n seconds. Have a look at this answer to help you out - [how to schedule ajax calls every N seconds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1350446/how-to-schedule-ajax-calls-every-n-seconds).

```
setInterval(displayOutput, (10 * 1000));
// reload log contents every 10 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you want basic XMLHttpRequest usage.

I am not really php guy, neiter javascript guru, just trying to give you an idea

```
function refreshText()
{
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else // for IE 5/6, just in case
    {
        xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xhttp.open("GET","/page.php?action=download_log_file", false);
    xhttp.send();

    document.form.text1.value = xhttp.responseXML;
}
setInterval(refreshText, (10 * 1000)); // refresh text1.value every 10 seconds
```

same thing using jQuery

```
setInterval(function {
        $.get('/page.php?action=download_log_file', function(data) {
            $('#text1').val(data);
        });
}, (10 * 1000));
```

The handler script at the server just prints file data, see
http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_server.asp for example

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented "COMET-like" functionality recently to do just this. The way it works is to have an AJAX poll with a long timeout:

```
var lines = 0 

function getLog(file, lines) {

    $.ajax({
              type:     'POST',
              url:      'http://thissite.com/getLogFile.php?File=' + file + '&Lines=' + lines,
              dataType: 'json',
              timeout:  400000,
        error:
            function() {
                return false;
            },
        success:
            function(data) {
                if (data.Error) {
                    alert(data.Message)
                } else {
                    if (data.Lines > lines) {
                        // do something with data.LogLines, e.g. add to a textarea
                    }
                    getLogFile(file, data.Lines)
                }
            }
    })
}
```

The back end script then simply loops like this:

1. Count the number of lines in the log file
2. If it's the same as lines, sleep (say for a second), then go back to 1
3. If the number of lines is greater, return the new lines, and the new line count, and exit
4. After some number of iterations (I use 100), exit and return the existing line count

The data structure returned by the back end script is JSON:

```
{
    Error: // 0 or 1,
    Lines: // Number of lines
    Text: // New lines from log file
}
```

This works just like 'tail -f' in UNIX, but in a browser!