# Multiple XmlHttpRequests every x seconds

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, settimeout, setinterval

i need some help on some code that i m writting..
my code fires three asychronous requests and updates some content on my page.
i want these requests to be fired every X seconds..
i have seen several questions like this, [how to schedule ajax calls every N seconds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1350446/how-to-schedule-ajax-calls-every-n-seconds) regarding setTimeout or setInterval, but the issue is that i need each request to be fired every x seconds..while the only i can think of that setInterval / settimeout wouldn't count seperate time for each call, but just one time..
for instance

> if i have xhr1 at 00.00.01 xhr2 at 00.00.02 and xhr3 at 00.00.03

what aproach would it be best for the next call to be after 20seconds for each?

> xhr1 00.00.21 xhr2 00.00.22 xhr3 00.00.23
>
> xhr1 00.00.41 xhr2 00.00.32 xhr3 00.00.33

also my current code is writen in that way that every xhr is fired after response of previous has been received using a callback function

```
function request(url, callback){
....
asychronous request
....
callback(responseText);
}

request(url1, function(){
some code
}
request(url2, function(){
some code
}
request(url3, function(){
some code
}
```

if another approach is suggested as well for the three calls, i would like to know..

Comment: "my current code is writen in that way that every xhr is fired after response of previous has been received" : could you clarify if you want to keep this behavior, or change it?

Comment: As long as this behavior is considered as good practice, i would like to keep it, but it is also important each request to be fired again after specific time.

Comment: What exactly is the ajax request doing. Is it loading html into a div or is there some processing going on after it returns?

Comment: Each xhr is taking html content of a different web page and i use inner html to extract specific content from each page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As this is an intricate scenario, I'd recommend that you look into [promises](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2011/09/11/asynchronous-programming-in-javascript-with-promises.aspx). It's not an easy concept, but it'll allow you to keep a clear separation of concerns between your chaining needs and your callbacks.

Without promises, you would need to include the next xhr call in your callback.

Promises are included in JavaScript libraries like jQuery or Dojo.

A simpler scenario would be to forget about chaining the requests:

```
function allRequests(){
request(url1, function(){some code});
// url2 one second later
setTimeout(function(){request(url2, function(){some code});},1000);
// url3 one more second later
setTimeout(function(){request(url3, function(){some code});},2000);
}
// run the 3 requests every 20 seconds
setInterval(allRequests(),20000);
```

Comment: what would you recommend Christophe to simplify this? add a single counter just to the firstrequest and embed the others into a function?

Answer (score 1):

Some options are:

Do all three requests at the exact same time. Is there a reason that all three requests cannot be done at the same time?

```
setInterval( allRequests, 20000 );

function allRequests() {
   requestOne();
   requestTwo();
   requestThree();
}
```

Or chain your requests using the success function of the previous request.

```
setTimeout( requestOne, 5000 );

function requestOne() {
   // do request blah blah
   setTimeout( requestTwo, 5000 );
}

function requestTwo() {
   // do request blah blah
   setTimeout( requestOne, 5000 ); // loops back to first request
}
```

Or stagger your requests at the start with timeouts.

```
setInterval( requestOne, 20000 ); // set first interval to start now
setTimeout( function() {
   setInterval( requestTwo, 20000 ); // set second interval to start one second from now
}, 1000 );
setTimeout( function() {
   setInterval( requestThree, 20000 ); // set third interval to start two seconds from now
}, 2000 );
```