# Show and auto update values of MySQL DB in the web page if they are updated in the DB

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, iot, mysql-python

I am taking values from sensor at an interval of 1 second. These values are being stored in MySQL DB. This is an automatic process.

Now I have made a website(free hosting) to show these values. The problem is, to see the updated values i have to refresh the browser. But I want the values to update automatically without refreshing the browser.

I am using PHP and MySQL

I have searched online and I saw some AJAX tutorials. But in those tutorials, you have to do something(Press a button) to update the values without refreshing the page. I want to update the values as soon as they are updated in the DB automatically.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: js\ajkax is the way to go, you need the client side to poll the server side

Comment: You can set a timer in Javascript to cause the AJAX function to be called. (i.e. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4542863/jquery-ajax-call-with-timer)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to schedule ajax calls every N seconds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1350446/how-to-schedule-ajax-calls-every-n-seconds)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with jQuery/AJAX, you’ll have to learn a bit to do this but it is very easy. What you should do is this, in js:

```
$.post("filename.php",{parameter:value}, function(data) {.$("elm").html(data);});
```

Something like this. You put it in a function and the you write this at the end of the script

```
setInterval(yourfunction(), time)
```

And then everything is ok. Go check a little lesson of jQuery, and you should understand this

Comment: Was my answer usefull?